# Notepad ++ search & replace for string between variables

Tags: notepad++, kml

I've been poking around and trying to find the solution to this problem I have but I haven't had any luck. Sorry if this has been covered before.

I need to pull a string of text out of a variable line and replace it with different variables.

Currently it is:

```
<SimpleData name="HDRNAME">Uprr #43 Pan Am B #12</SimpleData>
```

I need it to look like:

```
<name>Uprr #43 Pan Am B #12</name>
```

This is a huge *.kml file generated by a back end inventory program that really isn't playing nice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is to replace `<(/)?[^>]+>` with `<$1>`. Just select regular expression when you do it.

Try it: http://regex101.com/r/lP9iK0/1

Alternatively: Replace `<[^>]+>([^<]+)</[^>]+>` with `<name>$1</name>`.

Try it: http://regex101.com/r/lP9iK0/3

Note in regex101, the slash has to be escaped, but it doesn't in Notepad++.

---

Please consider bookmarking the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496) for future reference.